# How to access local path via Apache web server

Tags: linux, apache, webserver

I want to access my local home folder, via the apache webserver. if I do `http://localhost` it points to `/var/www/html` folder. I need to access `/home/username/mysite` folder via localhost. How do I do it?

In other words, what should I type in, in the browser address bar, to access mysite's folder? (I know I could move my site to the /var/www/html) folder, but I want to know whether this is possible.

Comment: to access files from browser directly, you can use `file:///C:/somefile`

Comment: Configure user's home directory support in your httpd.conf (your Apache main configuration file). Another way is using alias for paths in the same file. Restart Apache after modifs.

Comment: yes but I need to access it via, the webserver, so that other computers in my LAN also can access

Comment: please can you elaborate more on how to change the http.conf file